# Dealing with higher amount of events on angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar

We're currently starting to build an appointment system based on [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar). We're curious about any performance tips or considerations we should have in mind when dealing with a relatively big amount of events (~120 per day).

Is there anything in particular we should do or try to avoid in order to maintain good performance (as in responsive UI and memory consumption) on the frontend ?

Comment: Definetely, you need a good app arhitecture! See common angular perfomance tips for huge data-sets.

Answer (score 1):

Might use layering.  I would regularly refresh your calendar (I use a cron job every 10 minutes) to build your daily JSON events object with daily summaries as your events, so each day would show 1 event titled "250 appts." and clicking on that event would popup the list of appts. for that day, with each appt having bubble help with some data like title="2:30-Bob-ConfRoom#5" and clicking it would popup the details for the appt.